# The css selector that was compiled by sass is bad for browser

Tags: css, sass

SCSS code:

```css
#main {
  width: 97%;
  p, div {
    font-size: 2em;
    a { font-weight: bold; }
  }

  pre { font-size: 3em; }
}
```

is compiled to:

```css
#main {
    width: 97%; 
}
#main p, #main div {
    font-size: 2em; 
}
#main p a, #main div a {
    font-weight: bold; 
}
#main pre {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

Browser do not like a lot of nested selectors and repetition of parent selectors. So, which is best way to write SCSS?

Comment: This question may get dinged for inviting opinion-based answers, but I find it interesting.  While browsers may "dislike" lots of nested selectors and repetition of parents-- it is not the most efficient way for CSS to be interpreted-- CSS is generally very fast, so you would need to have a very large set of rules before I think you would note a perceivable issue.  Sass is a maintainability tradeoff for a minute performance cost.  I would say avoid needless nesting-- it doesn't need to mirror your markup structure-- and you should be fine.  Just my opinion, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way is to get rid of all this nesting, if possible. If you can, just add classes to these `p`, `div`, `a`, etc., and then create the CSS rules based on the classes, without nesting.

It might seem a little bit verbose in the beginning, but you will notice very soon how easier and more robust this approach is.